# When I search for my domain in Google it returns it in a foreign language

Tags: google-search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfoph.png)

When I search for `veski.com.au` in Google the result is returned in a foreign language. This site is built in Drupal, the translation is disabled and always has been. There are other domains pointing to this IP and they all return english as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is actually returning different content to Google than it is to users. You can use a tool like [RedBot](https://redbot.org/) to test this. Here is [a request](https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.veski.com.au%2F&req_hdr=User-Agent%3AMozilla%2F5.0+%28compatible%3B+Googlebot%2F2.1%3B+%2Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fbot.html%29) that pretends to be Google. If you click `view body` you will see a page full of Japanese characters. You can also try googling `cache:www.veski.com.au` to see what Google is being given.

Your site may have been hacked or this may be a misconfiguration. Either way, we need more details to be able to help. Check out [Google's advice](https://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/) for recovering from such a situation.